# Message: element not intractable still not working even after a time.sleep() and WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this has been asked lots of times before but how do you get around the "element not intractable" exception?

I'm pretty new to Selenium so excuse me if I get something wrong or misunderstood.

I have tried adding time.sleep(20) in various parts of the code to see if this allows the element to load but no success as yet.

Am I missing something here?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


#Login Credentials
email = 'anexample@fakeemail.com'
password = 'Password123'

#Login to Money Dashboard
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://my.moneydashboard.com/")

loginPageEmail =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input_0"]')))

loginPageEmail.send_keys(email)
```

I always get an error along the lines of:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "mdash.py", line 26, in <module>
         loginPageEmail.send_keys(email)
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
 line 479, in send_keys
         'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
 line 633, in _execute
         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
 line 321, in execute
         self.error_handler.check_response(response)
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
 line 242, in check_response
         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
     selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
       (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
       (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac
 OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the element id `attribute` is dynamic every time you run the code.So name `attribute` should be `unique attribute` here to access the `input` element .However Without form element it is not identifying the `input` element so I have used the form element along with input element and unique property of input element.

Use `WebdriverWait` and `elementtobeclickable` and following `xpath`.

```
    email = 'anexample@fakeemail.com'
    password = 'Password123'

    #Login to Money Dashboard
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://my.moneydashboard.com/")
loginPageEmail = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@name="vm.registerForm"]//div[@class="inputs"]//input[@name="email"]')))
loginPageEmail.send_keys(email)
loginPagepassword = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@name="vm.registerForm"]//div[@class="inputs"]//input[@name="password"]')))
loginPagepassword.send_keys(password)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Worked like a dream @KunduK - as I'm still learning can you expand on why your solution worked?

Comment: Should be noted that the main difference here is that the OP used `presence_of_element_located` and this answer uses `element_to_be_clickable`.  One waits for the element to exist, while the other waits for it to be inter-actable!

Comment: @Ardesco : Yes,I forgot to mentioned that.